# Hydrolysis of alkali and alkaline earth metals

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, hydrolysis, alkali-metals, alkaline-earth-metals

> Which of the following cations are not hydrolysed in aqueous solution?
> 1) $\ce{Mg^2+}$ 2) $\ce{Ca^2+}$ 3) $\ce{Na+}$ 4) $\ce{K+}$

I thought nothing would undergo hydrolysis, so all the options would be correct.

But my answer key says only $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{K+}$ wouldn't hydrolyse.
Why is the case?

Comment: Think about it this way, If it forms a hydroxide in water which is precipitated, can't we say it is hydrolyzed?

Comment: Neither calcium nor magnesium comes close to precipitating a hydroxide as a result of hydrolysis.  It takes an accurate pH measurement to detect hydrolysis of either of these ions in dilute solution, especially calcium.  I would have used iron(II) and zinc for my two hydrolyzing choices, that would better correlate with the real chemistry.  Too bad we can't give -1 to the book.

Answer (score 2):

Hydrolysis is a reaction with water, producing two new ions. Doubly charged ions, like $\ce{Ca^{2+}}$ or $\ce{Mg^{2+}}$ may react with water and produce complex ions like :$$\ce{Ca^{2+} + H2O -> [Ca(OH)]^+ + H+}$$ $$\ce{Mg^{2+} + H2O -> [Mg(OH)]^+ + H+}$$ These complex ions are well known in chemistry. Their existences explain why poorly soluble calcium salts like $\ce{CaSO_4}$ are much more soluble in water than what could be calculated from their solubility products. The solubility product gives only the value $\ce{[Ca^{2+}]}$ and does not give the concentration of the hydrated complex $\ce{[Ca(OH)]^+}$.

This sort of reaction is impossible with singly charged ions like $\ce{Na^{+}}$ or $\ce{K^{+}}$, because these alcaline ions cannot fix a $\ce{OH}$ group without being immediately dissociated.

Comment: While aqueous calcium does form $\ce{CaOH^+}$ as a minor species, the "excess" solubility of  calcium sulfate could be more related to the $\ce{CaSO4}$ ion pair.

Comment: @ Oscar Lanzi. Right. Thank you for your information.